# Múltipla condição C#

Tags: c#

Estou tentando validar se um usuário é professor e se ele digita "s" ou "n" maiúsculo ou minúsculo porem esta **ficando preso no loop** com a condição sendo verdadeira ou falsa.

`while ((array [i, 1] != "S") || (array [i, 1] != "s") || (array [i, 1] != "n") || (array [i, 1] != "N"))`

Comment: Olá Paulo, é importante [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado pela compreensão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paulo, experimente trocar o operador Or (||) pelo And (&&).
Como você está comparando o mesmo elemento com mais de um valor, com certeza ele vai ser sempre diferente de pelo menos  um deles.

Espero que ajude